# Is there an advantage of using GPT model compared to BERT if you have a specific domain?

Tags: natural-language-processing, chat-bots, chatgpt, gpt, watson

ChatGPT really shines when the task/question is very broad and is general. Using it and then limiting it's knowledge to a specific domain (via prompts as far as I know) would be kind of a waste of GPT.

Is there any advantage of choosing GPT instead? maybe the learning process can be easier and faster than other NLP like BERT?

Comment: ChatGPT is a GPT model, so it's unclear to me if by GPT you're referring to the original GPT model or not.